# Cargar select con MVC

Tags: c#, select, entity-framework

Como puedo mandar una lista a un select con MVC

No me muestra nada que puedo hacer?

Tengo mi codigo HTML:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<body onload="combo()">
    <div class="container body-content">
        <h5><span>Selecciona una Opcion:</span></h5>
        <select id="id" name="id_xxx" class="form-control dropdown-toggle" onchange="combo"></select>
    </div>    
    <script src="~/JS/XXXXX.js"></script>
</body>
```

codigo JS

```
function combo() {

    var x = document.getElementById("id");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'GetCombo',
        data: "",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
    
}
```

controller

```
public class xxxxx: Controller
    {
        // GET: XXXX
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();

        }

        public List<combo> GetCombo()
        {
            List<combo> lista = new List<combo>();
            lista.Add(new combo()
            {
                idOption = ""
            });

            using (var contex = new XXXXXXEntities())
            {
                var query = from s in contex.XXXXXX orderby s.XXXXX ascending select new { s.X, s.X };
                foreach (var item in query.ToList())
                {

                    int X = Convert.ToInt32(item.X);

                    lista.Add(new combo()
                    {
                        X = X,
                        idOption = item.idOption.ToString()
                    }); ;
                }
            }
            return lista;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Una forma de pasar datos entre el controlador y la vista en ASP.NET MVC es usando la propiedad `ViewPage.ViewData`, la cual es un diccionario que puede usarse para asociar valores de tipo clave-valor.

Ahora bien, dado que lo que quieres pasar a la vista es una lista de datos, podemos usar en combinación la clase `SelectList`, que sirve para representar una lista de elementos con un valor y un texto.

El controlador se vería algo así.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // SelectList recibe tres argumentos
    // 1. Un enumerable de los datos que harán parte de la lista
    // 2. El nombre del campo que se usará como valor del option
    // 3. El nombre del campo que se usará como texto del option

    // Se podría usar en lugar de strings quemados, la expresión nameof
    // Ejemplo, nameof(combo.idOption) 
    ViewData["combo"] = new SelectList(GetCombo(), "idOption", "X");
    return View();
}
```

Luego, en la vista para poder acceder al `ViewData`, se puede hacer lo siguiente.

```
<select asp-items="@ViewData["combo"] as SelectList"></select>
```

Este TagHelper se encargará de las opciones del select a partir de la lista proporcionada.

Nota que este ejemplo que proporcione configura el select al inicio, y luego retorna la vista al cliente. Si quieres mandar algún dato en respuesta a un evento del usuario, tendrias que usar js para traer los datos y mostrarlos.